# How to center title vertically in HighCharts pie/donut chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have a HighCharts Pie chart configured as a "donut" style, and I set the title "verticalAlign" to "middle" but this seems to center the title in the whole area taken up by the chart (including the legend) which is fine for a few data points, but once the chart has many points added, the title starts overlapping the colored segments and even the legend.  Is there a way to center the title in just the donut?

Example:
[image]

Comment: Could you please share your a minimal, reproducable code?

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts has quite a number of ways to adjust the style. Not clear how you display your title, but it seems that the problem is in the height of your legend. One way to go is to adjust the 'y' parameter of the title to move title a little:

```
title: {
    text: 'A title to move',
    align: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    y: -20,
    
}
```

Drawback is that it may not fill all the possible chart content, so you have to somehow estimate how much you want to adjust the 'y'.

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/title.y

Comment: Exactly, like @Vladimir M said, for more clear I share an online example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5vtdo0wh/

Comment: That was my original problem; how to "estimate how much to adjust the 'y' value"... with the chart set to default behavior, it's simply too complicated to try to follow the HighCharts logic in my server-side code. I ended up forcing the chart into various constraints (see below) to make it more 'static' and then adding a custom DIV with relative positioning to yield an acceptable result that worked for the varying series lengths I would encounter.

Comment: @JasonJohnson well... your question did not mention that and you did not provide any code to look at.

Comment: @VladimirM sorry I didn't reply sooner; here's a JSFiddle demonstrating how I solved this issue for my particular use case: https://jsfiddle.net/raphs3b0/

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, the final solution for my specific use-case involved:

- Fixing the 'chart.spacingTop' parameter to 10 pixels.  This fixed the top of the chart so it wouldn't dynamically change in the vertical space.
- Setting 'plotOptions.pie.size' to '250px'. This fixed the pie size to 250px regardless of how many points were shown.
- Setting 'plotOptions.pie.center' to '['50%', 105]'.  This centered the chart at 50% width, 105px from the top.
- Limiting my series to 24 data points max (to avoid a legend that was too long to manage)

Finally, I created a `<div>` right before the chart container that allowed me to use CSS to set it relative to the chart, positioning my label right in the center of the donut.

The result:
[image]